# sql server 2008 update table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have stored procedure that insert data to table
on this procedure after inserting data to the table i want to update data in this table by execute another procedure
but the data not updated.

just when i exec the updateTable procedure after the first procedure it works, but i need to exec the updateTable procedure from the first procedure!!!

this is the first procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE a  
AS
BEGIN
insert into tbl
select * from tempTable

exec updateTable
end
```

the procedure that update the table look like this:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[updateTable]
AS
BEGIN
    update tbl
    set tbl.name= users.name
            from  dbo.tbl tbl
                    inner join  
                  dbo.users   users 
                    on users.id=tbl.id
END
```

what can i do????

Comment: both procedures exist in the same DB right?

Comment: Note that your `update` statement is only updating rows where there is a match between `tbl.id` and `users.id`.  Are you certain that there are rows that should be updating?  If you, for example, change all the names in `tbl` to `ABCD`, then run the `insert` statement, are all the names updated back to original names?

Comment: Why not just do it in one procedure?